# Main function in my package doesn't work

Tags: warning-messages, packages

I am new to Mathematica package development and I have been trying to write and run some simple packages to get a feel for it. I wrote the following package.

My aim is to define a package which has a function named FusionCoef whose argument is a square matrix. The function then returns a list of lists.

```
BeginPackage["Fusion`"]

FusionCoef::usage = "Argument is the S-matrix. It returns fusion coeffients as a
list of lists"

Begin["`Private`"]
FusionCoef[K_] := Module[{n = 1, M, S = IdentityMatrix[3]},
   S = K;
   n = Length[S[[1]]];
   M = Table[Sum[(S[[i, m]] S[[j, m]] S[[k, m]])/(S[[1, m]]), {m,1,n}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, 
  n}];
   M
  ];

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

While running this package I am getting several errors like

```
<< Fusion`

Part::partd: Part specification S[[1]] is longer than depth of object.

Part::partd: Part specification S[[1,1]] is longer than depth of object.

Part::partd: Part specification S[[1,1]] is longer than depth of object.

General::stop: Further output of Part::partd will be suppressed during this calculation.

Part::pkspec1: The expression k cannot be used as a part specification.

Part::pkspec1: The expression k cannot be used as a part specification.

Part::pkspec1: The expression k cannot be used as a part specification.

General::stop: Further output of Part::pkspec1 will be suppressed during this calculation
```

I believe that the problem is with the way in which I have defined a function with matrix valued arguments. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Restart the kernel, make sure that the contents of your package are really what you show here, and try again. I do not see anything wrong with the package.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, the package is exactly what I have written here. But the problem persists. I did restart the kernel too.

Comment: Then you are not loading this package, but something else. Use ``FindFile["Fusion`"]`` to find out what.

Comment: Does the output of ``FindFile["Fusion`"]`` match your expectation?

Comment: It does. In fact, I have another package that I wrote in the same folder which is loading and working without any problem.  FindFile["Fusion`"] gave the output '/misc/strings_home/krishna/.Mathematica/Applications/Fusion.wl'

Comment: FindFile["foo`"] gave the output '/misc/strings_home/krishna/.Mathematica/Applications/foo.wl'. The foo.wl package is running without any problems.

Comment: If we cannot reproduce the issue, then it is very difficult to help. All I can say is that the code you quote cannot possibly cause these errors.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I am using Ubuntu. Will that possibly cause some issue?

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the error (on macOS). Please make sure that no other conflicting folders or files named `"Fusion.m"` or `"Fusion.wl"` are located in `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]`.

Comment: Can you post the result of ``CloudPublish@Trace[Get["Fusion`"], TraceInternal -> True]``? That should give you a link to the trace of the package import, which should help to investigate your issue

Comment: When I run CloudPublish@Trace[Get["Fusion`"], TraceInternal -> True], I am getting all the above errors along with 'CloudObject:: An unknown error occurred.' and the output was '$Failed'.

Comment: You use K as a variable, but K is built-in symbol. On some machines, this causes a conflict.

Comment: No, I do not think it has anything to do with Ubuntu. You are certainly not running (only) the code you show here. To solve this issue, triple check that you are indeed running this code, and find the difference.

Comment: For a start, this error would come from trying to use this function (which might or might not have problems—I did not check). Loading the package does not evaluate the function. It only defines it.

Comment: Why set `S = IdentityMatrix[3]` if you just overwrite `S` in the first line of the Module?  Perhaps `K` is a scalar and that is your issue.

Comment: @Edmund Yes, it does look like that function has several issues, but the OP claims that he never calls that function, thus it cannot possibly cause this problem.

Comment: I installed the package by going to File->Install and then used <<Fusion` Now things are working fine. Earlier, I had put the wl. file that I wrote into the User Base Directory. But, this doesn't seem to work. So, I let mathematical put a copy of the package into the UBD by using Install. I should have tried this earlier. Apologies if I lead to unnecessary confusions. Now the package and the function is working fine.

Comment: That means that your claim that `FindFile` returned the file you were working with was incorrect.  -1 for not paying attention after countless warnings that you are *not* running the code shown here.

Comment: FindFile indeed did return the file I was working with. I only had one copy of Fusion.wl in my whole system and that was in the UBD. Mathematica was aware that file named Fusion.wl is in the UBD, but it ran it as a package only after I explicitly installed the package rather than copy-pasting it into the UBD.  I have always been working with the same file Fusion.wl which has exactly the same code as above the whole time. From now on I will install the package using the install option within Mathematica instead of just saving or copy-pasting the package that I write into the UBD.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to include it in a package, a function should be validated as a ordinary function. I think your definition of `FusionCoef` needs to be corrected to something like this:

```
Clear[FusionCoef, squareMatrixQ]
squareMatrixQ = (MatrixQ[#] && With[{d = Dimensions[#]}, d[[1]] == d[[2]]] &);
FusionCoef[sq_?squareMatrixQ] :=
  Module[{n},
    n = Length[sq[[1]]];
    Table[
      Sum[(sq[[i, m]] sq[[j, m]] sq[[k, m]])/(sq[[1, m]]), 
      {m, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}]]
```

Then

```
m = FusionCoef[Array[s, {3, 3}]];
Dimensions @ m
```

> `{3, 3, 3}`

```
Column[MatrixForm /@ m]
```

[image: matrix]

Since I am not familiar with your problem domain, I am not sure this is really the function you need, but it is certainly an improvement over your version and, at least, I hope it will help you to move forward with your package building.

Note: I put the above definitions into the private section of your package code and ran the package and it performed without any errors.

Comment: Fun note, `SquareMatrixQ` is a built-in

Comment: @b3m2a1. That's embarrassing. I swear I checked the docs for it before writing my own version and can't understand how I missed it. Am editing the answer to used the built-in.